# When to use % after a command

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing

I am writing my own class file and when I am browsing through code developed by
others I see % sign popping up at the end of command lines while other authors
do not use it. Consider the
following example from `biblatex`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Here the % sign is used after the second and third line. Other others only use it
in constructs like

```
\newcommand*{\bla}{%
  \a
  \b}
```

where % is only present at the first line. Finally there are authors that use it almost
everywhere (after every line). As a class/package writer what should I do?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the above question, but to rephrase the answer, just use a `%` if, if writing the code on one line, you do not want a space at that point.

Comment: In your two examples I would use `%` as shown in the second, and in the first I would add `%` on line 6

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a complete answer, but whitespace after a command such as `\a` does not count. So, in your second example, there is no need to add `%` after `\a`.